# Is $ c \exp(-\frac{1}{2}(\beta^T \beta + (y-X \beta)^T(y-X \beta))$ (for appropriate $c$) the PDF of a multinormal distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a PDF for (vector) $\beta$ that is proportional to $\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\beta^T \beta + (y-X \beta)^T(y-X \beta)\right)$ where $X$ and $y$ are a fixed matrix and fixed vector, respectively. Is this a multinormal distribution for $\beta$? I cannot seem to re-arrange it into the canonical form $\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}((\beta-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (\beta-\mu)\right)$ for a multinormal PDF -- but the textbook I'm reading implies (but doesn't prove) that this distribution is indeed multinormal. (It's reasonable to assume that $X$ has full rank if that makes a difference.)

Comment: Have you tried to rearrange into the case where the normal distribution is not centered at zero? You might try "completing the square" (with matrices and vectors and not simply numbers)

Answer (score 1):

As Benjamin suggests above, completing the square solves the problem. In particular,
$$
\beta^T \beta + (y - X \beta)^T (y - X \beta) = \beta^T \beta + \beta^T X^T X \beta - 2 \beta^T X y + y y
  = \beta^T (I + X^T X)\beta - 2 \beta^T X^T y + y y
$$
Of course, $I + X^T X$ is symmetric. Given the context (a statistics textbook), it is reasonable to assume this matrix is also invertible. Therefore, as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square#Matrix_case), we can complete the square in $\beta$. Ignoring the constant terms, the result is:
$$
(\beta - (I + X^T X)^{-1} X^T y)(I + X^T X)(\beta - (I + X^TX)^{-1} X^T y)
$$
So, the distribution is indeed multinormal with mean $(I + X^T X)^{-1} X^T y$ and covariance matrix $I + X^T X$.